# Why "Go get dressed" instead of "go dress"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Considering that ['to dress' is a verb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dress), why is it preferable to say "Go get dressed" as opposed to the simple "Go dress"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Dress* is a transitive verb, meaning that it takes one or more objects. *Go dress* doesn't contain any objects, so the sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read about [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb). I suppose that one might say "Go dress yourself", then?

Comment: @dotancohen exactly.

Comment: user132181: I disagree. 'Dress' is transitive or intransitive in different sentences. Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English gives 'Aunt Margaret told her to dress herself in her nicest dress', 'I dress the kids before I go to work' (trans), 'I've got to go home to dress', 'I dressed quickly' (intrans).

Comment: @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher I completely agree I was wrong. Please, provide the right answer so OP can accept it and I can delete mine (right now I can't because it's accepted).

Answer (score 2):

*Dress* is one of those words where if there is no object expressed, an reflexive object like *myself, yourself*, etc. can be understood, like *wash*, *bathe*, *clean*, etc.

So you can tell someone to *go dress.*

However this usually means to dress for a specific reason, such as a ceremony, function, costume party, etc.

*Go get dressed* is idiomatic for putting on your normal clothes of the day.